# Gem Command not found

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I have installed gem on Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit with

```
apt-get install gem -y
```

But when I try to run

```
gem install something.gem
```

I get the error of the command not being found.

```
bash: gem: command not found
```

I installed gem, is there any reason it is saying it can't find the command?

These files were install by gem package

http://pastie.org/3483416

Comment: It says     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies
/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/ga
mes

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Are you wanting ruby gems? If so, you need to install libgemplugin-ruby and then the ruby 'gem' program will be in your path:

```
aptitude install libgemplugin-ruby
```

Comment: wich mirror do you use to find this package? I cant find here with the default raspbian sources.list.

Answer (score 143):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

Comment: Whats the difference between this and installing just `ruby`?

Answer (score 23):

The following command installs ruby gem for ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libgemplugin-ruby
```

I did it after ruby was installed.

Comment: Unable to locate package for Ubuntu 18 ! :(

Answer (score 22):

Installing this package allows you to use `gem` command on Debian 8:

```
apt-get install rubygems-integration
```

To install a gem package you might also need:

```
apt-get install ruby ruby-dev
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Answer (score 16):

On Debian, Ubuntu or Linux Mint:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rubygems ruby-dev
```

On CentOS, Fedora or RHEL:

```
$ sudo yum install rubygems ruby-devel
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I wanted to install gem for centOS and this solution worked.

Answer (score 10):

FWIW, the equivalent package for RHEL/Fedora/CentOS/etc and SuSE/OpenSuSE appears to be called 'rubygems'.

Answer (score 9):

The following command may help you

> sudo apt-get install ruby

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 14.04,

`apt-get install ruby ruby-dev`

this will install `gem` for you.

Answer (score 6):

On CentOS 7 you can do:

> yum -y install rubygems-devel

That worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. What I did was:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then reinstall ruby-full

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

Answer (score 3):

check that rvm is a function `type rvm | head -1`

Comment: Worked for me. I was getting error while the command output was: **rvm is /home/zesaver/.rvm/bin/rvm**. Then I added to my .bashrc: **[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function** . And reopened my terminal. Now the answer was: **rvm is a shell function**. And gem command started to work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kind of late for a response. But I did run into this error and I found a solution here:
https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

You just have to enable  'Run command as login shell' under the terminal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will give you the list of files that the gem package installed:

```
dpkg -L gem
```

that should help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, I ran it and got a list of files

Answer (score 1):

try

$ `/usr/bin/pd-gem`

or

$ `pd-gem`

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 8:

eventually, download the file of the application:

```
wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/asciidoctor-2.0.16.gem
```

then execute:

```
yum install -y rubygems ruby-devel
gem install asciidoctor
```

More: I tried positively also in a container (using the appropriate RUN and COPY statements before the commands).