# RVM not installing gems to /bin on Macbook

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I have a relatively new installation of `rvm` to use to manage Ruby and now I am trying to install gems and use them. I can perform `gem list` and see the installed gems:

```
jblanchard$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 3.0.4)
date (default: 2.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
locksmith (0.1.1)
...
```

When I perform `gem env` I see the executable directory:

```
jblanchard$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.1 (2019-01-30 patchlevel 33) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jblanchard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jblanchard/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jblanchard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jblanchard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jblanchard/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jblanchard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/etc
```

However, none of the gems are in the *bin/* and I get a "command not found" when trying to use them. I have found the gems in the *cache/* directory, but adding that directory to the path doesn't help.

```
cache jblanchard$ ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   5 jblanchard  staff    160 Feb 26 08:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 jblanchard  staff    352 Feb 25 12:40 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jblanchard  staff  13312 Feb 25 12:40 gem-wrappers-1.4.0.gem
-rw-r--r--   1 jblanchard  staff   8192 Feb 26 08:02 locksmith-0.1.1.gem
-rw-r--r--   1 jblanchard  staff   7680 Feb 26 08:02 tuwaga-0.0.3.gem
```

I have tried all of the suggestions in [Gem Command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9485083/1011527), [Ruby Gems returns "command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392293/ruby-gems-returns-command-not-found) and a couple of other answers here on Stack, to no avail.

Here is my *.bashrc* file where paths are defined.

```
# Add gems executable path..
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Have I done something wrong? Shouldn't rvm put the gems in the *bin/*? Is there something I can do to make sure gems are installed there?

Comment: For example, which command did you try?

Comment: I tried `locksmith getpair -j my-app` @zeitnot. From that I got "command not found".

Comment: Would you try `bundle exec locksmith getpair -j my-app`?

Comment: @zeitnot that returns `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Comment: Are you able to use rbenv instead?

Comment: Try `find ~ -name locksmith -perm +u+x 2>/dev/null` that will tell you if a locksmith executable was installed anywhere in your home directory. Failing that, try `find /` instead to see if it's anywhere on your computer. My guess is you are somehow installing the gems to the wrong place

Comment: I could @JaredMenard, but exactly how many Ruby managers should I employ? :)

Comment: @Max Gems are being installed in the *cache/* folder, instead of *bin/*.

Comment: The `find` does not return anything @Max

Comment: @JayBlanchard, good point. I hope you find a solution to your issue. Cheers.

Comment: @JayBlanchard if find isn't returning anything, your gem executables aren't being installed _at all_. Is there some rubygems config to not install gem executables? It's very strange that it thinks they're installed but they don't exist anywhere on your hard drive.

Comment: Agreed @Max - it is very strange. We were able to come up with a hacky work-around, but I don't want to post that as an answer, because it is a one-off.